# Angularjs ng Grid, unable to show data for some ng grids when their columnsDef in Grid Options is different during multi ng grids display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to display multiple ngGrids in a single button click. But the problem is coming when the columnDef option in the Grid options are different for these Grids. Please find my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/y878sCsl3PJ04MhcAKYI?p=preview. Here when we click 'create multiple ng grids', Grid 2 and Grid 3 data is appearing fine, for these two columnsDef in Grid options is same. However Grid1 data is not appearing, its columnDef in Grid Options is different from Grid2 and Grid3. For reference I have separated them individually through 'Create ng Grid1' and 'Create ng Grid2', which are working fine. The same grids I am trying to create together using 'Create Multple ng Grids' button. But the first grid data is not appearing. Can any one help me to fix it?

The following is my Grid Options setting code :

```
if (dashletteId == 1) {

    $scope.myData = $scope.tabs[dashVar].data;
    $scope.myColumnDefs = $scope.getColumnDefs($scope.tabs[dashVar].columns);
    $scope[gridOptions] = {
        data: 'myData',
        showGroupPanel: true,
        jqueryUIDraggable: false,
        columnDefs: $scope.myColumnDefs
    };



} else {


    $scope.myData = $scope.tabs[dashVar].data;
    $scope.myColumnDefs = $scope.tabs[dashVar].columns;
    $scope[gridOptions] = {
        data: 'myData',
        showGroupPanel: true,
        jqueryUIDraggable: false,
        columnDefs: $scope.myColumnDefs
    };
}

$scope.getColumnDefs = function( columns ){
    var columnDefs = [];

    columnDefs.push({field: 'mode', displayName: 'Mode', enableCellEdit: true, width: '10%'});
    columnDefs.push({field:'service', displayName:'Service', enableCellEdit: true, width: '10%'});

    angular.forEach(columns, function( value, key ) {
        columnDefs.push({field: key, displayName: value, enableCellEdit: true, width: '10%' })
    });

    return columnDefs;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all of your 3 grids `columnDefs` are pointing to `$scope.myColumnDefs` ends up that all grids columnDefs are evaluated to the same array.

you might need to separate the scope variable to be assigned to columnDefs.

```
var template = '<div class= "chartsDiv">';

var config = {
    1: {
        gridOptions: 'gridOptionsOne',
        data: 'dataOne',
        columnDefs: 'colDefsOne'
    },
    2: {
        gridOptions: 'gridOptionsTwo',
        data: 'dataTwo',
        columnDefs: 'colDefsTwo'
    },
    3: {
        gridOptions: 'gridOptionsThree',
        data: 'dataThree',
        columnDefs: 'colDefsThree'
    },
};
for (var dashVar = 0; dashVar < $scope.tabs.length; dashVar++) {
    var name = "Recovery";
    var dashletteId = $scope.tabs[dashVar].dashletteId;
    var axisType = $scope.tabs[dashVar].axisType;
    var chartName = "chart" + name.replace(/ +/g, "") + dashVar;
    var tableData = "chart" + name.replace(/ +/g, "") + dashVar;
    var gridOptions = "gridOptions" + chartName;


    if (axisType == "table") {


        if (dashletteId == 1) {
            $scope[config[dashletteId].columnDefs] = $scope.getColumnDefs($scope.tabs[dashVar].columns);
        } else {
            $scope[config[dashletteId].columnDefs] = $scope.tabs[dashVar].columns;
        }
        $scope[config[dashletteId].data] = $scope.tabs[dashVar].data;
        $scope[config[dashletteId].gridOptions] = {
            data: config[dashletteId].data,
            showGroupPanel: true,
            jqueryUIDraggable: false,
            columnDefs: config[dashletteId].columnDefs
        };

        template += ' <div class="col"> <p class="graphtitle">' + $scope.tabs[dashVar].dashletteName + ' </p> <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="' + config[dashletteId].gridOptions + '"></div>';
    }


}

template += ' </div>';
//  alert(template)
angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));
```

Comment: How can I do  it? I tried $scope[myColumnDefs] = $scope.tabs[dashVar].columns; but it is not working either? Sorry for my late response.